# Getting npm ERR! 404 'esprima@https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master' is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, github, npm, http-status-code-404, package.json

During jenkins build getting the below error and build is getting failed

```
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://codeload.github.com/ariya/esprima/legacy.tar.gz/master

npm ERR! 404  'esprima@https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master' is not in the npm registry

npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'jshint'

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

we are using node js.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?